# Create database explicitly before restoring to it?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-backups, database-restore

When I setup my PostgreSQL server one of the first things I will do is import a database for an external source. Which of the following is the right way to do it?

- Create a database called "NEWDB" on the PostgreSQL server and then
  import my external "BACKUPDB" database from my pg_dump into the
  "NEWDB".
- Don't create a database on the PostgreSQL server, and import the
  "NEWDB" database, thereby automatically creating "NEWDB" on the
  postgresql server.

I guess my question is, if I want to import an existing database to the PostgreSQL server, do I first need to create a database for it to go into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *have* to. It depends on what you want to achieve. If you dump a **single database** with [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html), `CREATE DATABASE` and `ALTER DATABASE` commands are not included. You are expected to connect to an existing database. So you have to create it first.
I quote [advice from  the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html):

> If your database cluster has any local additions to the template1
>   database, be careful to restore the output of pg_dump into a truly
>   empty database; otherwise you are likely to get errors due to
>   duplicate definitions of the added objects. To make an empty database
>   without any local additions, copy from template0 not template1, for
>   example:
>
> `CREATE DATABASE foo WITH TEMPLATE template0;`

And also:

> The dump file also does not contain any ALTER DATABASE ... SET
>   commands; these settings are dumped by pg_dumpall, along with database
>   users and other installation-wide settings.

[`pg_dumpall`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pg-dumpall.html), on the other hand, dumps the whole **DB cluster** including meta-objects like users. It includes `CREATE DATABASE` statements and connects to each DB when restoring. You can even include `DROP DATABASE` statements with the `-c` (`--clean`) option. Careful with that.

Every instance of PostgreSQL has a default maintenance db named "postgres" that you can connect to - to create databases for instance or start a full restore (from pg_dumpall). But a single-DB dump (from pg_dump) has to be run against its target database.

Finally:

> Once restored, it is wise to run ANALYZE on each database so the
>   optimizer has useful statistics. You can also run vacuumdb -a -z to
>   analyze all databases.